# Mounting a folder on the host as the postgres config directory/

Tags: docker-compose

I have a git repo with my app, with a `docker-compose.yml` in the root for running an environment. It uses postgres 9.1 for the database (that will be upgraded). The postgres part of the config looks like this:

```
db:
  image: orchardup/postgresql:9.1
  ports:
      - 5432:5432
  environment:
      POSTGRESQL_USER: XXXXXXXXX
      POSTGRESQL_PASS: YYYYYYYYY
      POSTGRESQL_DB: my_scharona
```

I'd like it so that `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main` in the container be mounted from `db/etc` in the git repository so I could store the postgres configuration files in git. However, when I do this in the yml file:

```
    volumes:
      - ./db/etc:/etc/postgresql/9.1/main
```

I get the following error when starting the containers:

> ERROR: Cannot link to a non running container: /ZZZZZZ_db_1 AS /ZZZZZZ_web_1/db

From what I've read [in the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/compose/yml/#volumes) I seem to be using the right syntax. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Using `docker-compose up db` to launch just the db instance exposed the actual error:

```
zippy1981@zippy1981-Inspiron-15-7568:~/src/XXXXXXXXX$ docker-compose up db
Recreating XXXXXXXXX_db_1
Attaching to XXXXXXXXX_db_1
db_1 | postgres cannot access the server configuration file "/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory
```

Since I forgot to put the config files on the host PostgreSQL didn't start.